# How to use jigsaw with Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

I am trying to experiment with project Jigsaw as per this link http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/quickstart.html

However, I cant find `jmod` command in the Java 9 early access build. Similarly, javac emits an error message saying

> javac: invalid flag: -modulepath".

Any idea? What is the best way to experiment with Jigsaw in Java 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the preparatory [JEP 201](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/201) and [JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) are both present as of JDK 9 build 41, the main Jigsaw work for [JSR 376](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec) is not yet present.

In response to [a similar question on the mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.macosx-port.devel/6900), about that quickstart guide:

> This is a quick start documentation from the original Jigsaw prototype 
>   of a few years ago, I guess it's a reminder that some of these obsolete 
>   pages needs to be updated to make it clear that they are obsolete.

and about the current state of the work:

> JSR 376 is just starting and so there isn't a JEP for the module system 
>   yet. It will all come in time.

So, as of March 2015, the OpenJDK 9 builds don't include Jigsaw support. The [jigsaw-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/) is the best place to look for progress. It [also confirms that status](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2015-February/004181.html):

> So too early to be looking for options like -modulepath.

It's likely that Jigsaw-specific builds will be made available ahead of inclusion in the regular JDK 9 builds.

Answer (score 3):

There are now [early access builds available with Jigsaw](https://jdk9.java.net/jigsaw/)

Answer (score 1):

After so many delays,  the latest information is that Java 9 will FINALLY be released Sept 21.

Please use its released version for try, we have seen SO MANY changes related to Java 9, hopefully, it will be stable after public release.

related info: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2017-June/005867.html

BTW:the best place to check java 9's status is at  its architect's twitter:

https://twitter.com/mreinhold